# Handling popup windows in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, browser, automation

I am entering a password and checking if it's work or not.
[image]

After entering wrong password, site reloads and pop up appears.
[image]

How do I deal with the popup? For example, how can I automatically click an element in the popup?

My Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
     while (2>1):
              Sam = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id=1]")
              Sam.send_keys(i)
              login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id=2]")
              login.click()
              if EC.alert_is_present:
                   browser.switch_to.alert.accept()
              else:
                  print i
                  break;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    sexy()
  File "<pyshell#57>", line 3, in sexy
    browser.get('http://eps.gpeonline.co.in/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 264, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette
```

Comment: It seems that error has nothing to do with alert handling. Your script failed to execute `browser.get('http://eps.gpeonline.co.in/')`

Comment: @Andersson But if i remove `if` and `else` and manually click `ok` script is working fine

Comment: try  Event scheduler after the page loads.

Comment: @NarendraModi **Off-topic:** I think you have bigger problems than popup, or form validation. If officials in India find out you're impersonating their prime minister, you're not going to see a terminal in a few decades. Also Andersson is right. Consider giving him the check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `EC.alert_is_present` incorrectly: your `if` condition will always return `True` as `EC.alert_is_present` is just a class. Try to use below `try`/`except` block instead of `if`/`else`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

try:
    wait(browser, 1).until(EC.alert_is_present()).accept()
except TimeoutException:
    print i
    break
```

This should allow you to accept alert if it present or print `i` and break loop if it didn't appear in 1 second (you can change timeout value if required)